# How to load complete package with Jaxb

Tags: java

I am trying to load the package with Jaxrb.

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("abc.acs");
Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
```

But during marshalling I am getting an exception

> "abc.acs" doesn't contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index .

How to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class)` for the respective `ObjectFactory`.

Comment: Object factory means Jaxb factory or else

Comment: `ObjectFactory` means the specific class that's in the JAXB package for whatever schema you are using.

Comment: I don&#39;t have schema I have a simple xml and I like to convert into pojo . I don&#39;t have any schema. If u have an example can u please post it for reference. But with package , when I load with class it doing fine, but when I change with package I am getting an error

Comment: Well, that's not how JAXB works. To unmarshal an object using JAXB, you have to have some sort of mapping telling JAXB what type of XML is it and how it maps to a Java object. If you want a framework for serializing POJOs as XML without a schema, you might want to look into XStream instead.

Comment: Can u please post a reference for me it will be great with schema

Comment: And if you DO want to use a schema and generate the JAXB mappings, then instead look at the XJC tool: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/xjc.html

Comment: Thanks it will help me